# Angular 4 and ASP.Net MVC 5 : returns an Empty JSON in response

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, angular

after merging angular app with asp.net MVC calling API from angular returns an empty JSON.

The angular and asp.net are in the same domain.

If I call the API With PostMan, I have a JSON with the result. but if I call it in the angular app my JSON result is empty.

Are there any tips for communicating angular app with asp.net MVC after merging and serving in the same domain?

**Update 1:**

The code that used to calling Webservice:

```
 getSheets(): Observable<Sheet[]> {
return this.http.get(this.config.apiUrl + '/api/SheetsRelationAPI', 
this.jwt())
  .map(this.extractData)
  .do(data => console.log('SheetsData:', data))  // debug
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }


/**
* Handle HTTP error
*/
 private handleError(error: any) {
// In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
// We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
  error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

// private helper methods

 private jwt() {
// create authorization header with jwt token
const currentUser = JSON.parse(atob(this.cookie.getCookie('currentUser')));
  if (currentUser && currentUser.access_token) {
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.access_token},
  );
  return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  }
  }
   private extractData(res: Response) {
const body = res.json();
return body || [];
 }
```

**Update 2:**

I notice that my API if I called it from outside domain it respond 2 times:

inspecting network with google chrome inspect element:

the first response is "zone.js" initiator and the second response is an "other" initiator

If I call the API from inside of the Domain I just have a response from "zone.js" initiator and it returns an empty JSON.

**Update 3**

```
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
sheets: Sheet[] = [];
errorMessage: string;
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    // this.sheets = this.ichartHttp.getSheets();
    // console.log(this.sheets);
}
getSheets() {
    this.httpService.getSheets()
        .subscribe(
        sheets => this.sheets = sheets,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getSheets();
}
}
```

Comment: and whats your new angular code that you are using to call the webservice?

Comment: @Unlockedluca I update my question

Comment: Where do you call the `getSheets()` method?

Comment: In my OtherComponent that calls getsheets method

Comment: Maybe you could share that as well. Because this part looks fine.

Comment: @s.alem I update my question again, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with my Authentication methods,
I use two types of authentication, MVC and WebAPI they conflict if I send a request to API under the same Domain.

So my Answer is: Your Angular Code looks good, take a look at your middleware project